Ruby on rails - Error Uninitialized constant twilio when initializing its instance
I am getting error while creating client instance in twilio. Below is the code and error
uninitialized constant LogInController::Twilio
Extracted source (around line #26):

              
        auth_token = "-------AUTH TOKEN-------"
        account_sid =  "------ACCOUNT SID------"
a = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token.  #Line 26
puts "---a---#{a.inspect}------"
    end


Rails.root: /Users/anujasharma/Desktop/projects/Rails/ezy_management

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/log_in_controller.rb:26:in `send_otp_for_verification'

class LogInController < ApplicationController

    def login
        if request.post?
            # employee = Employee.where(username: params[:username]).first
            
            # if params[:password] == employee.password
                send_otp_for_verification
                # redirect_to verification_path
            # end

        end
    end

    private
    def send_otp_for_verification
        auth_token = "2155542f2ad56da976ff54bf14a893a4"
        account_sid =  "AC79354dbeb69e9fb76625c5d687323ef3"
a = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
puts "---a---#{a.inspect}------"
    end


    
end

Firstly, I installed 'twilio-ruby' gem and then this code. Nothing extra I did.
Also, tried
::Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

PS: Trying to learn this Don't mind for silly mistakes.

It seems you exposed you auth key in this question. I'd recommend that you delete the question and rotate the auth token

@IObert Even if the question is deleted it's still visible for people with enough reputation

Thanks a lot for this. Although, it was not the correct auth token and sid but still I removed them.

How did you install the twilio-ruby gem?
When the twilio-ruby gem was installed with gem install twilio-ruby then it needs to be required manually in the application. This is usually done by adding
require 'twilio-ruby' 

to the top of the file in which the gem is used.
When the gem was installed with bundler by adding gem 'twilio-ruby' to your application's Gemfile, then I suggest checking if bundle install was called after adding it to the Gemfile.

Yes, I solved this. Actually I installed gem from console and didn’t add require before using it. Thanks a lot for explaining this.
